# LyX, Error Converting to Loadable Format for PDFs under Ubuntu

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I have the same problem as reported [Lyx, Error Converting to Loadable Format for PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326244/lyx-error-converting-to-loadable-format-for-pdfs) but I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and solutions are only described for Windows and MacOS.

Here are the stderr messages if I run LyX from the command line:

```
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.mJCcewM29047/gconverts29047.eps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.mJCcewM29047/gconverts29047.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

The LyX wiki solutions https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/FiguresInLyX also don't apply, since my versions are:

> ImageMagick 6.9.7-4
>
> Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)

My `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<!--
...(comments excised for brevity)...
-->
<policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> 
-->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
  <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPI" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
</policymap>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 18.04. This thread helped me solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-erro

Comment: @scottkosty Curiously, my policy.xml file already looks like the updated version.

Comment: Can you convert the PDF on the command line? Can you give the terminal output, if there is an error, when you try the conversion on the command line (i.e., outside of LyX)?

Comment: `convert myPDFfigure.pdf myPDFfigure.png` works perfectly on the command line. I'm actually not clear on what the conversion that LyX needs is. PDF->png is not listed in the LyX converter definitions.

Comment: I suggest first to run `lyx` from the command line and reproduce the error, then look at the terminal. Any helpful messages?

Comment: @scottkosty Thank you! I've done that and edited my question

Comment: Good. Next step: open LyX, reproduce the problem, and then (without closing LyX) in a terminal window copy "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.*" to e.g. your desktop. Now you can exit LyX. Then go to the folder you copied, and try running the command `convert-im6.q16 gconverts29047.eps blah.png`. Can you reproduce the same error? The goal with all of this is to reproduce the error outside of LyX so we can isolate the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that, and reproduced the "not authorized" error. But in fact your instructions contained the answer: the conversion is not from PDF but from EPS. So I changed  `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />` to  `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />` in policy.xml, fixing the problem.

Comment: Great! Go ahead and add & accept your answer to mark this is solved. Glad it's sorted out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to edit ImageMagick's `policy.xml` file. Even though it was a PDF that I supplied to LyX, and LyX ends up with a PNG, it was lacking permissions  for EPS (PS).

Thus, in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` I changed

`<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />`

to

`<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />`

Diagnosis all thanks to @ScottKosty; see comments following my question.

Comment: Just worked for me on Linux Mint 19.3.